# Как сделать POST-запрос с параметром?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Как сделать запрос не пустой, а с POST-параметром запроса (к примеру id)?

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> infoList;
private static final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.0.1/array.php";
loadJSONFromURL(JSON_URL);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//начало:
private void  loadJSONFromURL(String url){

//создание запроса для отправки запроса по URL-адресу:        
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override           
    public void onResponse(String response) {

//получение всего объекта json из ответа:
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

//у нас есть массив с именем users внутри объекта
//итак, здесь мы получаем этот массив json: 
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("users");
                ArrayList<JSONObject> listItems = getArrayListFromJSONArray(jsonArray);

//создание пользовательского объекта адаптера:
                infoList = listItems;
                ListAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,R.id.textViewName,listItems);

//добавление адаптера в listview:
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

//отображение ошибки, если происходит:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

//теперь перебираем все элементы массива json:
private ArrayList<JSONObject> getArrayListFromJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
    ArrayList<JSONObject> aList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try {
        if(jsonArray!= null){
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                aList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        }
    }catch (JSONException js){
        js.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать POST-запрос, поменяйте метод запроса с `Method.GET` на `Method.POST`.

Чтобы указать параметры POST-запроса, переопределите метод `getParams()` у класса `StringRequest`. В примере ниже для параметра `id` передается значение `42`:

```java
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.POST, url,
        response -> {
            // обработка результата
        },
        error -> {
            // обработка ошибки
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", "42");
        return params;
    }
};
```